# How do I group two items in a list of tuples as a dictionary?

Tags: python

I want to summarize the fruit and colour. There are a list of tuples with fruit and its corresponding colour, and I want to count the fruit in colour of yellow, then construct a dictionary:

```
yellowfruit= { 'banana': 1, 'grape' : 2, 'orange': 2, 'peach': '4', 'pear':1 }
```

The following is the information of the fruit

```
    fruit= [
                 ('apple', 'green' ),
                 ('apple',  'red'),
                 ('banana', 'yellow' ),
                 ('grape',  'green' ),
                 ('grape', 'yellow' ),
                 ('grape',   'yellow' ),
                 ('grape',  'red' ),
                 ('orange',  'yellow' ),
                 ('orange',   'yellow' ),
                 ('mango',   'green' ),
                 ('peach',   'yellow' ),
                 ('peach',   'red' ),
                 ('peach',   'yellow' ),
                 ('peach',  'yellow' ),
                 ('peach',  'red' ),
                 ('peach',  'yellow' ),
                 ('peach',   'red' ),
                 ('pear',  'yellow' ),
            ]
```

These are my codes with comments:

```
fruit= [
         ('apple', 'green' ),
         ('apple',  'red'),
         ('banana', 'yellow' ),
         ('grape',  'green' ),
         ('grape', 'yellow' ),
         ('grape',   'yellow' ),
         ('grape',  'red' ),
         ('orange',  'yellow' ),
         ('orange',   'yellow' ),
         ('mango',   'green' ),
         ('peach',   'yellow' ),
         ('peach',   'red' ),
         ('peach',   'yellow' ),
         ('peach',  'yellow' ),
         ('peach',  'red' ),
         ('peach',  'yellow' ),
         ('peach',   'red' ),
         ('pear',  'yellow' ),
    ]

yellowfruit = { } # create an empty dictionary 
fruitname = fruit[0][0] # 'apple' is the first fruit
for i in range(len(fruit)): # loop over the tuples in the fruit list

    if fruit[i][0] == fruitname:
        if fruit[i][1] == 'yellow':
        # for the same kind of fruit, if its colour is yellow, count update for 1
            n += 1
        else: # if the same kind of fruit but not the colour of yellow
            continue

    else:
        n = 1 # if not the same kind of fruit, refill the count as 1
        fruitname = fruit[i][0] # if the fruit change, always update the current item as the fruit name
    yellowfruit[fruitname] = n # create the dictionary 

print(yellowfruit)
```

The result:

```
{'peach': 4, 'banana': 1, 'orange': 2, 'grape': 3, 'pear': 1, 'mango': 1}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You'd just do `collections.Counter(f for f, c in fruit if c == 'yellow')`

Comment: You start with `n = 1` *whether or not it's yellow*. Also it would be helpful to explain why you expected different output, so readers don't have to diff it themselves.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Even I change the if statement as 'if fruit[i][0] == fruitname and fruit[i][1] == 'yellow':', it does not work.

Comment: I can't say I'm surprised, given that the problem I just highlighted is in the `else` part. Try running your code with http://pythontutor.com/ to see what's happening, I think you'll spot the problem.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks so much, I just know this good tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're relying on the tuples being sorted by fruit, but that may not always be the case. To handle the two cases where the fruit either does or doesn't exist in the dictionary `yellow_fruit`, we use `yellow_fruit.get(fruit, 0)`, which either returns `yellow_fruit[fruit]` (if `fruit` exists in `yellow_fruit`) or `0` (if it doesn't exist). Note that dictionaries are unordered, so the printed key/value pairs can permute themselves if you rerun the program.

```
tuple_list = [
    ('apple', 'green'),
    ('apple', 'red'),
    ('banana', 'yellow'),
    ('grape', 'green'),
    ('grape', 'yellow'),
    ('grape', 'yellow'),
    ('grape', 'red'),
    ('orange', 'yellow'),
    ('orange', 'yellow'),
    ('mango', 'green'),
    ('peach', 'yellow'),
    ('peach', 'red'),
    ('peach', 'yellow'),
    ('peach', 'yellow'),
    ('peach', 'red'),
    ('peach', 'yellow'),
    ('peach', 'red'),
    ('pear', 'yellow'),
]

yellow_fruit = {}
for fruit, colour in tuple_list:
    if colour == 'yellow':
        yellow_fruit[fruit] = yellow_fruit.get(fruit, 0) + 1
print(yellow_fruit)  # {'banana': 1, 'orange': 2, 'grape': 2, 'peach': 4, 'pear': 1}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! My problem is solved and you make me know dict.get() is so helpful!